# Put an array of Objects in nodes of another array of Objects [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object[] newarray = new Object[1];
        Object[] obj = new Object[2];

        obj[0] = "Number1"; //string value
        obj[1] = "Number2"; //string value

        newarray[0] = obj; //this works

        Object[] tmp_obj = new Object[2];

        tmp_obj = newarray[0]; //obviously does not work
        System.out.println(tmp_obj[0]); //nope
        System.out.println(tmp_obj[1]); //nope
    }
}
```

So, now if I want to access the values "Number1" and "Number2" which are stored in obj[0] and obj[1]; **obj is in newarray[0]**. what should I do?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. tmp_obj = new_array[0] = obj

Comment: @mdma That was the catch! Interesting problem with a simple solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a cast:

```
tmp_obj = (Object[]) newarray[0];
```

That says, "I know that newarray[0] isn't just any old Object - it's an Object[]" (Modulo array variance; let's leave that out here.)

Note that the `new Object[2]` from the previous line will be instant garbage - the code would be better as:

```
Object[] tmp_obj = (Object[]) newarray[0];
```

Comment: I thought it implicitly casts.

Comment: @jonathanasdf: An implicit cast from `Object` to `Object[]`? Absolutely not.

Comment: @zengr: I'm glad it works for you - do you understand *why* it works, or do you want some more detail?

Comment: Yup, I got it! Object and Object[] are not the same. So you need to cast the values of the newarray[0] to another object array (tmp_obj).

Comment: why not just allocate and initialize an Object[][] and avoid the casts?

Comment: @mdma was a "concept clarification question" rather an actual implementation question. I can also say, why not use Ruby and avoid the data type problem :P